# The canonical map $H^1(Y, f_*\mathscr O^*) \to H^1(X, \mathscr O^*)$ and $f^* : \operatorname{Pic}Y \to \operatorname{Pic}X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying remark 2.11 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504020.pdf#section.2).

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and assume that $\mathscr O_Y \to f_* \mathscr O_X$ is an isomorphism.
By Leray spectral sequence we have the canonical map $H^1(Y, f_*\mathscr O^*) \to H^1(X, \mathscr O^*)$.
Since $H^1$ is equal to its Cech version, and since $\check{H}^1$ is equal to $\operatorname{Pic}$, compositing $\mathscr O_Y \to f_* \mathscr O_X$, we have $\operatorname{Pic}Y \to \operatorname{Pic}X$.
Does this coincide with the pullback $f^* : \operatorname{Pic}Y \to \operatorname{Pic}X$?

I know that the Cech-derived isomorphism is induced by a spectral sequence $\check{H}^p(X, \mathscr{H}^q (-)) \Rightarrow H^n(X, -)$.
(where $\mathscr{H}^q$ is the right derived functor of the forgetfull functor from the category of sheaves to one of presheaves on $X$.)

I think if we can take "nice" injective resolution of $\mathscr{O}^*$, we can compute the desired map between Pic.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it's better to just do it Cech wise and note that what the cocyle is doing is just pulling back the invertible overlap maps. Check that the pullback of the line bundle is the same thing.